# calling xml file and swf files in html page

Tags: html

How i can call xml  and swf files  in html page i hav to display flash image

Answer (score 0):

Start learning from:

http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/XML/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Flash can be easily embedded as follows: (Some help from [this site](http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashhtmlcode.php)) Basically, just change the filename to the correct one, the size, etc, and you're good to go.

```
<embed src="example.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
width="468" height="60" 
name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 
</embed>
```

XML data is a bit trickier, the best way is with some javascript. This example taken from [this page](http://www.expertrating.com/courseware/XMLCourse/XML-Embedding-HTML-8.asp).

```
<xml Id = msg>
<message>
               <to> Visitors </to>
               <from> Author </from>
               <Subject> XML Code Islands </Subject>
               <body> In this example, XML code is embedded inside HTML code </body>
</message>
</xml>
```